# Kernel dies when training XGBoost regressor with GPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm trying to build a simple XGBRegressor model.  It runs fine for a few seconds and then kernel dies without any error messages.  There are no error messages in the terminal too when run with the debug flag.

I tried the following things already:

1. The problem occurs within a Jupyter notebook as well as when the same code is run as a simple '.py' script
2. It doesn't seem specific to my environment as I'm able to consistently repro the issue even on Kaggle's GPU kernels
3. The same code runs fine if I turn off GPU with 'tree_type' flag
4. I looked into the event viewer on windows for some error codes and found this which didn't offer much insight:

> Fault bucket 1757117266428035048, type 5 Event Name: BEX64 Response:
>   Not available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: python.exe P2: 3.7.3150.1013 P3: 5c9bf5b3 P4:
>   ucrtbase.dll P5: 10.0.17763.404 P6: 490b0aeb P7: 000000000006e91e P8:
>   c0000409 P9: 0000000000000007 P10:

```
import os os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True' from xgboost import XGBRegressor

best_params = {'learning_rate': 0.16, 'n_estimators': 100, 
               'max_depth': 6, 'min_child_weight': 7,
               'subsample': 0.9, 'colsample_bytree': 0.7, 'nthread': -1, 
               'scale_pos_weight': 1, 'random_state': 42, 

               #next parameters are used to enable gpu for fasting fitting
               'tree_method': 'gpu_hist', 'max_bin': 16, 
               'gpu_id': 0
              }

xgb_model = XGBRegressor(
        **best_params)

xgb_model.fit(
        cur_train_x, 
        cur_train_y, 
        eval_metric="rmse", 
        eval_set=[(cur_train_x, cur_train_y)], 
        verbose=True, 
        early_stopping_rounds = 10)
```

My GPU is a 950 GTX with only 2GB dedicated memory.  Windows task manager shows another 8GB shared GPU memory.  Is it crashing since the dataset doesn't fit completely within the dedicated GPU memory?

Any insight or direction as to how I can get at a helpful error message or a solution would be very appreciated.